# How do I find out which flatpak sdk provides a certain library?

Tags: flatpak

I'm trying my hand at packaging an application using [flatpak](http://flatpak.org). The metadata is pretty simple at the moment:

```
[Application]
name=io.brackets.App
runtime=org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.20
sdk=org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/3.20
command=brackets
```

The application depends on certain libraries not contained in the sdk, as it fails at runtime:

```
/app/bin/brackets: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know how to find out the proper runtime in RPM land, but how do I find out what provides these libraries in flatpak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GConf has been deprecated since (IIRC) the first release of Gnome 3, it's not in the Gnome runtime. You'll have to bundle it.

Using `flatpak-builder` this will end up as a module similar to the following

```
    {
        "name": "gconf",
        "config-opts": ["--disable-orbit"],
        "sources" : [
            {
                "type": "archive",
                "url": "http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/GConf/3.2/GConf-3.2.6.tar.xz",
                "sha256": "1912b91803ab09a5eed34d364bf09fe3a2a9c96751fde03a4e0cfa51a04d784c"
            }
        ]
    }
```

An example of this can be found in the [spotify flatpak wrapper](https://github.com/alexlarsson/spotify-app)